# Mounting google storage bucket folder using gcsfuse

Tags: gcsfuse

0
down vote
favorite

I am not able to mount a specific folder inside the google storage bucket

On OS X, this program allows you to mount buckets using the mount command. (On Linux, only root can do this.)

mount -t gcsfuse -o rw,user my-bucket /path/to/mount/point

On both OS X and Linux, you can also add entries to your /etc/fstab file like the following:

my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user

Can somebody help me?

my-bucket:foldername /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user

This doesn't work for me

---

Thanks for your reply. We mounted the bucket first using the above doucment

and later created a symbolic link to the mounted folder which makes it work

```
ln -s /mnt/s3/subfolderinsidebucket /your path
```

and in /etc/fstab

```
my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user
```

And again we faced a problem when the server restarted its not able to mount automatically

So we added an entry in crontab @reboot mount.sh
and added the mount command inside the sh file

Answer (score 1):

Follow this doc- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md

You have to add this in `/etc/fstab`:
`my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user`

after you can run `mount /mount/point` as a non-root user.

obs: the `noauto` option above specifies that the file system should not be mounted at boot time.

I don't know if you can mount a specific folder in the bucket, but you can try `my-bucket/foldername /mount/point gcsfuse rw,noauto,user` (change ":" by "/")

Answer (score 1):

@George's answer is close, but not correct for mounting a specific folder in the bucket.

To mount a specific folder in the bucket use this syntax:

```
my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,user,key_file=/path/to/key.json,only_dir=my_subdirectory
```

`only_dir=my_subdirectory` is the important part there.

You do not need a `key_file=` if you are mounting on a google compute instance.

Answer (score 1):

very very late but...
so,
to mount specific subdirectory of a bucket in a mount point:

--> command

gcsfuse -o option1,option2 --only-dir sub_dirirectory/ -key-file=/path/to/key.json bucket_name /path/to/mount/point

--> fstab

bucket_name /path/to/mount/point gcsfuse rw,user,key_file=/path/to/key.json,only_dir=sub_directory

Answer (score 0):

`gcfuse` allows you to mount a specific subfolder (with the content) witin a bucket, using the flags `--implicit-dirs` and `--only-dir`.

The correct syntax is

```bash
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --only-dir <subdir-relative-to-bucket> <bucket> <mount_point>
```

For example, in the cloud I have a bucket with the root `my_bucket` and a subdir `my_bucket/sub_dir/sub_sub_dir` which I want to mount into the local dir `mount_dir`, then I do

```bash
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --only-dir sub_dir/sub_sub_dir my_bucket mount_dir
```